# How to get the first child that is a specific element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This problem seems very simple, however I cannot get this to work.

I have the following simple markup.

```
<div id="left_pane">
<ul>
<div id="indicator"></div>
<li>Something</li>
<li>Something else</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I select the first item from the list that is a `li` element? (i.e. not the div).

I have tried many different ways... like this

```
#left_pane ul:first-child li {
    /* style */
}

#left_pane li:first-child {
    /* style */
}
```

But I can't seem to make anything work.

Comment: Do you know that your HTML is not valid? `ul` elements cannot contain anything else than `li` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first element of its type regardless of other elements of different types, you'll normally use the `:first-of-type` CSS3 pseudo-class.

But here, it's not valid HTML to have a `div` as a child of a `ul` in the first place, so you ought to move that inner `div` out. It should then be enough to use `:first-child` as per your second rule since a `ul` can only have `li` elements as children:

```
#left_pane li:first-child {
    /* style */
}
```

Comment: I suppose that browsers are correcting this and already move out the `div` element, which can make things even more confusing.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Firefox seems happy to keep the `div` in the `ul` anyway, which may explain why `:first-child` doesn't work with the OP's markup. Run `$('<ul><div></div></ul>').find('div')` in Firebug and check out the result.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm trying to make a little indicator which floats to the right of the list items - if I move it out of the ul the div doesn't align with the list properly...

Comment: Fixed - I thought it might not have been valid markup but it seemed to be the only thing that would get my indicator to align properly - I've now corrected it with negative margin